# Files disappear from sd card after unmount

Tags: sd-card, raspberry-pi-os

I have sd card with raspberry os installation that I use with PiZero.
I am trying to edit wpa_supplicant.conf from my arch pc.

after I connect and mount sd card to pc I can edit file like this:

```
sudo vim <mount_point>/rootfs/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

I am also able to create any file on partition.
But if unmount/disconnect sd card and remount/reconnect (without booting and placing sd card elsewhere) the files and changes are gone.
Why does it happen?

info on mount

```
mount | grep sdf
/dev/sdf2 on <mount_point>/rootfs type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sdf1 on <mount_point>/boot type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)
```

sudo fdisk -l

```
Model: Generic MassStorageClass (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdf: 3980MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      4194kB  48.0MB  43.8MB  primary  fat32        lba
 2      50.3MB  3980MB  3930MB  primary  ext4
```

UPDATE:

dmesg

```
[ 3598.359501] sd 11:0:0:2: [sdf] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=6s
[ 3598.359510] sd 11:0:0:2: [sdf] tag#0 Sense Key : Aborted Command [current]
[ 3598.359512] sd 11:0:0:2: [sdf] tag#0 Add. Sense: Incompatible medium installed
[ 3598.359514] sd 11:0:0:2: [sdf] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 41 80 08 00 00 08 00
[ 3598.359515] I/O error, dev sdf, sector 4292616 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x83700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
```

seems like sd card is failing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common failure mode for SD cards.  The blocks on your SD card are worn out, and it has run out of replacement blocks.  It is not accepting writes anymore.